# python package healthcare.ai load error

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax-error

I successfully installed the healthcare.ai python package, but could not load it. Here is the error message. Has anyone else experienced this before?

```
File "/Users/mshen/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/healthcareai/common/model_eval.py", line 142
    return {'accuracy': accuracy, **roc, **pr}
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone suggested that I should use Python 3 to install the package.

That indeed solved the problem (thanks & sorry I didn't get to accept your answer before it somehow disappeared).

Here's what I did.

1. install python 3

   `brew install python3`
2. create a python 3 virtual environment

   `python3 -m venv test3`
3. activate python 3 virtual environment

   `source ./test3/bin/activate`